# Example of a $C^{\infty}_c$ function?

Tags: functions, weak-derivatives

While studying weak derivatives I've searched for examples of these functions (compact support and $C^{\infty}$), but all I've found look like this one:
$$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             e^{\frac{-1}{1-x^2}} &   |x|<1 \\
             \\ 0 &  |x|\geq 1  \\
             \end{array}
   \right.
$$

Could someone give another example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function should help. 

In practice, the exact details of these function do not matter as much as the fact that they are smooth, compactly supported. You can have some degree of freedom in constructing them to your specific needs usually.

Comment: $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(-2^{n/2})\cos(2^n x)$ is infinitely differentiable but nowhere analytic. Proof and more details https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: Any product of your function and another $C^\infty$ function (not necessarily compactly supported) will also be in $C^\infty_c$.